# Z-Index In IE7 - Causing Nightmares

Tags: css, z-index, internet-explorer-7

I've got a drop down menu created in CSS. Works fine in all other browsers, apart from IE7. In IE7 the menu drops in terms of priority behind my home image and on subpages, It drops below a submenu.

An example of this is here : [Image Issue](http://koodoocreative.co.uk/~tbilaw/)

If you load the page in IE7 and then go to select an item from the "Personal" menu. As you can see the menu drops behind the image.

I tried to recreate this as a jsFiddle. It might be worth a look [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pGZxM/)

Starting to bug me now, As the rest of the site is done.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am happy to hear that you solved the Z-indexing issue in IE7. Right now you are facing problem with your Main dropdown menu because-

1. There is a gap between in your dropdown   links or between

   , thats why when we hove on the menu the menu disappear or we can say that once the cursor comes on gap the menu disappear.
2. You have given the `background-color #1C1C1C;` on  tag. Acc to me if you give on  or

   it will not show the gap but first try to solve the gap issue in IE7.

For testing purpose You can give css property `border:1px solid red;` on ul, li and anchor tags. It will help you to identify where is the gap or in which elements gap is occuring.

You have used IE7 specific css, you can try to write the css rule dedicated for IE7 there it self.

See attached image for IE7 output.

[image]

Regarding your sub menu under the main menu where your are facing the problem when hover the drop-down menu disappear. The padding you have given on  link might be not working properly in IE7 and another issue may be there is a gap between  link and there dropdown, you have used top:28px on line 357 in style.css try to increase/decrease the value and test it simultaneously in all browser so you can figure it out where is the problem.

Re: Try to give height to the main anchor tags for eg: on Employment Law etc. and again you can test it by giving  the border and background color to the anchor tags so you can identify the boundaries of your links.

Comment: First class answer. Thanks alot @Happy Singh I have managed to fix the gap issue by tweaking the height of the li anchor. It seems to have worked anyway. Thanks very much for your help on this